# What holds between $A' \times B'$ and $(A \times B)'$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

[image]

Please find below the problem and the way I did it. Can someone check whether there is a mistake in notation or anything wrong? Kindly correct me if there is anything wrong in my proof anywhere. I know the answer will be A' X B' = (A x B)'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post pictures. Many people don't see them and MathJax is searchable.

Answer (score 1):

$(A \times B)'=A' \times B'$ is false: in $X=Y=\Bbb R$ take $A=\{0\}, B=\Bbb R$.

$A \times B$ is closed and has no isolated points so $(A \times B)'= A \times B$ while $A'=\emptyset$ and so $A' \times B'=\emptyset$.

So the best you can hope for is $$A' \times B' \subseteq (A \times B)'\tag{1}$$ based on this example.

So let $(x,y) \in A' \times B'$, and $U \times V$ be a basic neighbourhood of it. Then there is some $x' \in A \cap U, x'\neq x$ as $x \in A'$ but also some $y' \in  V \cap B, y' \neq y$ as $y \in B'$, and then $(x',y') \neq (x,y)$ and $(x',y') \in (U \times V) \cap (A \times B)$ and as $U \times V$ was an arbitrary basic neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ we've shown that $(x,y) \in (A \times B)'$ and $(1)$ has been shown.

In fact, looking at the proof, we see we only need $y \in \overline{B}$ for the argument for the inclusion to work, so in fact $A' \times \overline{B} \subseteq (A \times B)'$ and symmetrically $\overline{A} \times B' \subseteq (A \times B)'$ as well.

We know that closures and products do behave well together in that

$$\overline{A \times B}=\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$$

and use that $\overline{C} = C \cup C'$ for any set, so that

$$(A \times B) \cup (A\times B)' = (A \cup A') \times (B \cup B') = \\
(A \times B) \cup (A' \times B) \cup (A \times B') \cup (A' \times B')$$

but we have no cancallation law (for unions) to get direct conclusions from that. It does suggest

$$(A\times B)' = (A' \times B) \cup (A \times B') \cup (A' \times B')$$

might hold, and you could try to show it yourself, using the proof technique for $(1)$.